# How to set up dual NICs?

Tags: networking, server, samba, ethernet

so I have just got a new motherboard for my Ubuntu 12.04 server and it has dual Gigabit Intel NICs. I use the server as an SMB file server and a Plex Media Server. Currently, I have 1 NIC connected and my `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like this:

`# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
 address 192.168.1.81
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 192.168.1.254
 dns-nameservers 192.168.1.254`

I know to start I will add an `auto eth1` but will this use the same IP address or will it have its own? I want it to act as though there is only one NIC, but that the NIC is 2 Gigabit so I could be copying a file to a samba share on it at ≈100mbps and then be able to stream something from Plex and utilise both NICs?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm fairly experienced with Ubuntu but not as much when it comes to networking. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Bonding, also called port trunking or link aggregation means combining several network interfaces (NICs) to a single link, providing either high-availability, load-balancing, maximum throughput, or a combination of these." -- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: I have correctly set this up and it works, however I am not seeing the performance benefit I was expecting. Have I done something wrong, or can I just never expect 2x performance from 2 NICs? When coping to an SSD on the server from 2 separate computers (both with single gigabit NICs) I get about 75mbps from each.